# Query where exists and does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my table structure

Table - User

COLUMNS - USERID~CREATEDON~...

Table - Audit

COLUMNS - AUDITID~OBJECTID~ACTION~...

User to Audit - 1 : N (USERID to OBJECTID)

I am trying to come up with a query which returns all users which have an audit entry with an action value of 64 or 65 (at some point beyond the last 6 months) *or* that do not have 64 or 65 at all.

Here is what I have come up with:

```
DECLARE @monthsInactiveFor INT
SET @monthsInactiveFor = -6     

SELECT USR.fullname, 
           USRID.last_logged_in_date 
    FROM   systemuser AS USR 
           INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT AB.objectid       AS USERID, 
                                       Max(AB.createdon) AS LAST_LOGGED_IN_DATE 
                       FROM   systemuserbase AS USR 
                              LEFT OUTER JOIN auditbase AS AB 
                                           ON USR.systemuserid = AB.userid 
                       WHERE  ( AB.action = 64 ) 
                               OR ( AB.action = 65 ) 
                       GROUP  BY AB.objectid 
                       HAVING ( Max(AB.createdon) <= 
                                Dateadd(month, @monthsInactiveFor, 
                                Getdate()) )) AS USRID 
                   ON USR.systemuserid = USRID.userid 
    WHERE  ( USR.isdisabled = 0 ) 
           AND ( USR.createdon <= Dateadd(month, @monthsInactiveFor, Getdate()) ) 
           AND ( USR.accessmode = 0 ) 
    ORDER  BY USR.fullname
```

The above query works fine and returns all records that have an audit table row with an action of 64 or 65 that weren't created in the past 6 months.

I am struggling to also have the same query look for users that do not have an audit entry at all with the ACTION column value of 64 or 65.

Any pointers in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: try Union

Comment: Why is there no date column in the audits table? One user can have many audits so the date of an audit is a property of audit (not the created date of a user row).

Comment: I am also checking for users who were recently created, under 6 months, as they may have not yet logged into the system. Hence the created date of user row check on top of audit created date check.

Answer (score 2):

There are only 3 logical groups of people:

1. People whose most recent 64/65 audit event is more than 6 months ago
2. People whose most recent 64/65 audit event is less than 6 months ago
3. People who have no 64/65 audit events

You want groups 1 and 3. Which is everybody except the people in group 2. So turn the logic around: If the Max CreatedOn of the audit event is in the last 6 months, then you **don't** want that user. You want everybody else.

Comment: If I used SELECT  * FROM X WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Y ON X.ID = Y.ID), won't I lose access to columns in Y table? More specifically in this case, last logged in time?

Comment: @dynamicallyCRM Store the result of the `USRID` subquery (except the `Having` clause) in a table variable. That gives the user and last login time. The `Not exists` subquery can select from this table variable with a `where LAST_LOGGED_IN_DATE <=   Dateadd(month, @monthsInactiveFor,  Getdate())`. and the main query can independently join to this table variable.

Comment: P.S. I suspect the DISTINCT may be redundant; but hard to tell without your data.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing a UNION to fetch all the records as the query is also more readable, any optimization suggestions are welcome:

```
SELECT USR.FULLNAME, 
       AUDUSR.LAST_LOGGED_IN_DATE 
FROM   SYSTEMUSERBASE AS USR 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT AB.OBJECTID       AS USERID, 
                                   MAX(AB.CREATEDON) AS LAST_LOGGED_IN_DATE 
                   FROM   SYSTEMUSERBASE AS USR 
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN AUDITBASE AS AB 
                                       ON USR.SYSTEMUSERID = AB.USERID 
                   WHERE  ( AB.ACTION = 64 ) 
                           OR ( AB.ACTION = 65 ) 
                   GROUP  BY AB.OBJECTID 
                   HAVING ( MAX(AB.CREATEDON) <= 
                            DATEADD(MONTH, @monthsInactiveFor, 
                            GETDATE()) ) 
                   UNION 

                   SELECT OBJECTID AS USERID, 
                          NULL     AS LAST_LOGGED_IN_DATE 
                   FROM   AUDITBASE 
                   GROUP  BY OBJECTID 
                   HAVING MAX(CASE 
                                WHEN ACTION = 64 
                                      OR ACTION = 65 THEN 1 
                                ELSE 0 
                              END) = 0) AS AUDUSR 
               ON USR.SYSTEMUSERID = AUDUSR.USERID 
WHERE  ( USR.ISDISABLED = 0 ) 
       AND ( USR.CREATEDON <= DATEADD(MONTH, @monthsInactiveFor, GETDATE()) ) 
       AND ( USR.ACCESSMODE = 0 ) 
ORDER  BY AUDUSR.LAST_LOGGED_IN_DATE, USR.FULLNAME
```